# Can I use a gas station air pump on a bike tire?

Tags: tire, pump

Someone pointed out that it may be risky, and it might not have the right kind of nozzle, but I don't have a bike pump at the moment.  Does anyone else ever do this?

Comment: The typical convenience store air hose provides 40 pounds max.  My touring tires run 90-100 PSI.  (But also be aware that some truck stop setups may deliver 150 PSI.)  You at least need a tire pressure gauge.

Comment: @DanielRHicks does that mean there are air hoses for cars _without_ a pressure gauge? How does one use them to check their car's tyre pressures then? Do you always have to bring your own pressure gauge in a car?

Comment: @gschenk - If there is a pressure gauge/regulator on the hose it's accuracy is maybe +/- 5-10 pounds, and it's reaction time is likely slow.  Not to be relied on.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer, in short is: Can you? In some cases, yes. Should you? In most cases, no.

The long answer: The reason you *can* sometimes use an automotive air-pump on a bicycle tire/tube is because they share an identical valve. (See: [Schrader valve/Schrader tube](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/284#284) in the [Terminology Index](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index)). If you have this type, you will definitely be able to get air into your tubes in a pinch. However, air hoses from gas stations are usually unregulated, high-pressure & high-volume, and lack a pressure gauge. Therefore, it is much easier to over-inflate and even blow out your bicycle tire, if you were to use one.

An investment in a bicycle pump is one of the best you can make as a cyclist. Not only will it get you out of situations like this, but it will make it easier to keep your tires at the recommended pressure rating, which in turn will make it easier for you to be a more efficient (read: faster) bicyclist.

Comment: Several bicycle pumps - ideally you need a track pump or similar to keep where you store your bike, check the pressures regularly (when I was commuting by bike I did it once a week when I got home) and a pump you carry with on the bike because, if one is not racing, then its just sensible to carry a pump and a few other bits with you at all times

Comment: Note also: if you have a Presta valve (thinner valve with a captive locknut, common on road bikes), you'll need an adapter to use a gas station pump.  The adapter is a cheap little $1 brass part that screws onto the presta valve

Comment: Yeah... be careful.  I blew out a tire doing this.  Was loud, and not fun.

Comment: It's also worth noting that many gas station pumps will not go over about 80psi. That means that even if you have Schrader valves or an adapter, you won't be able to get optimum pressure in road tires. It may be enough to get you home, but you'll have to be extra careful about bumps.

Comment: For completeness, the answer seems to depend on the country and the corresponding pump technology of its gas stations. Reading the answers here took my by suprise. Since I can think, I only buy tires with a Schrader valve in order to save me from the laborious act of using a bicycle pump. I am from Germany and most of the time, you'll find [such devices](http://data.motor-talk.de/data/galleries/0/18/3395/16560149/58331949-2332c45c3c-13182.jpg) at gas stations.

Comment: In Australia almost every service station has a digital air compressor. The danger with using them on bikes is that they work by reading the current pressure, then dumping a huge amount of air in at once, then reading the pressure again and so on. They're designed for cars so they could well dump way too much air in on the first pump and blow the tyre.

Comment: With experience, your fingers are the best pressure sensor, and right technique is the key. With the digital service station pumps, I just dial the highest pressure (usually 80 psi) and pump with one blow, feeling the pressure as it goes, disconnecting when enough. This, of course, mostly works with MTB tyres; for road ones, the max pressure is not sufficient anyway.

Comment: "and lack a pressure gauge" ? I have never seen a gas station where the tyre inflator thing does not have a pressure gauge (Germany, France, Switzerland). After all, car tyres also have a recommended pressure that drivers want to stick to.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this in a pinch if you're careful, but I don't recommend it.  Your tires need to have Schraeder valves (similar to car tires) or you'll need an adapter for a Presta valve.  Fill the tire in very short bursts, checking the pressure in between.  Err on the side of underfilling your tires -- put too much air in and you may blow the tire off the rim, which is worse than having a flat in the first place!

I used to do this 20 years ago before I realized that there were small pumps you can take with you.  In addition to the risks, the problem with gas station pumps is that they're never there when you need them.  The one repair kit you should have with you at all times is a pump + patch kit (or spare tube).  Trust me, it can be a long, long walk home without them!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but there are a few factors to consider:

- **Valve Type**, obviously it is easiest with a schraeder valve, as these are the type that cars use. You can get adapters for presta valves that screw on and allow you to use the service station pumps.
- **Tyre Volume**, as noted in some other answers, the air supply at service stations is often unregulated. The smaller your tyre, the faster the pressure increases - so you run more risk of over-inflation for narrow road tyres than for large mountain bike tyres.
- **Pressure**, road bike tyres are generally inflated to 110 - 130 PSI, which is much higher than the 30-40 PSI used for car tyres, or the 30-60 PSI used for mountain bike tyres. The service station pump may not be able to achieve this pressure, particularly if it is one of those automatic inflation types.

So, in short, if you've got a mountain bike, there is probably not much of an issue using the service station pump. If you've got a road bike, do yourself a favour and buy a decent track pump. That way you'll be able to top up the tyres quickly each time you go out, and enjoy the benefits of nicely inflated tyres.

Comment: True. Before searching for this answer I have tried hard to inflate bicycle tyre with my air pump for car. Unfortunately, it couldn't reach more than 80 PSI

Answer (score 3):

I would say it depends - here in the UK the air pumps at petrol stations all have pressure gauges of some sort, but many aren't suitable.
The digital ones where you select the pressure to which you want your tyre inflated often max out at 60psi* but that's not the problem - the problem is that they inflate for a bit then let a bit out to test and correct.  And they assume a car tyre. So to get a car tyre from say 30psi to 34, they might hit 46 and then let some out.  To get a bike tyre from say 55psi to 60 they will put enough air in to make a car tyre inflate by a few psi - meaning your bike tyre will get rather too hard.  I don't fancy measuring the peak pressure they'll do. That's why they say not to use them for bikes.

The older sort with a proper pressure gauge also generally have a trigger that you can press lightly, and should be OK.

I'm assuming you're sorted for valve compatibility here.

*not even high enough for my van, resulting in some hard work with my track pump to finish the job.

Comment: You're also assuming they're reasonably accurate (at least in the US, they're not. You need to use a handheld gauge to check it).

Comment: @Batman, that as well, I only know that when the air line in the garage near here maxes out at 60psi my track pump reads about 60psi. But this is a problem with pressure gauges in general - my old foot pump wasn't the cheapest but before it failed the gauge would tend to under read by a variable amount compared to my cheap little gauge.

Comment: This is the case in australia also.

Answer (score 2):

I use the air pump at gas stations all the time for years with no issue. The pumps with the air pressure gauge on the handle are best. One caveat, I never fill it to the recommended top of the scale psi, I always use about stop about 10 psi from full.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use gas station air pumps on a bike : Most likely especially for mountain bikes and BMX bikes (unless your tubes use a different valve type), Is it a good idea : Probably not, unless your very careful and have no other way to pump up a tire.

I've never had much of an issue using gas station air pumps with mountain bikes and BMX bikes, as most bike tyres I've seen use Pressures from 40-50 PSI, but I rarely go to the max to prevent a blow out which I've done a few times pushing the pressure to the max.

Most gas stations in Canada have pumps which have a built in pressure gauge on the handle, which works a lot like a tire pressure checker. Its probably not as accurate as other means but this is another reason why I wouldn't risk pumping a bike tire to max pressure.

Either way, since I'm a poor person who usually forgets to get things like tools and pumps when they have money, this is usually my only way of pumping up a bike tire when I don't have a pump at home. Though its so much better when you do have one at home so you don't have issues like having a soft/flat tire before you head out for work on bike or just want to run down to the store to get something.

Answer (score 1):

In New Zealand, just push the compressor hose fitting on to the valve real tight and hold it there with pressure. Then press the button that says flat tyre. Then you got to be fast at taking it off because it blows up almost instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a new bike with Presta valves. I went to buy an adapter for a Schrader valve so I can use my compressor or the pump at the gas station. The adapter does not work and here is the reason and what you need to do to fix it. The adapters are only designed for a bicycle pump not the Schrader chuck style at the gas station. The adapter is hollow and needs a center pin to push open the center pin in the pump head at the gas station.

It took a while of fiddling around and some more research on the net to realize this. It seems little is quite understood about this little trick.

Take a 2-inch nail and cut a billet from it about 8 mm long with a hack saw or angle grinder. Make the ends flat as best you can with a file or such. Undo the head of the Presta valve and place the tyre/wheel with the valve stem on the pavement, i.e., at 6 o'clock. Screw on the adapter and drop the small billet into the adapter. Now get the attachment from the pump at the gas station and proceed as if pumping up your car tyres. Do it in short bursts so as to not the blow the tube off the rim. Getting the right pressure is another question; there's more on the net about that. Keep the adapter and your hand made piece of artwork in an obvious place because the billet is very small. You can always make a new one.  There you go.

Comment: ...or you can buy a correct adapter.

Comment: The trick here is that presta valves are held shut by air pressure from the inside.  If you fully deflate them, then the stem will sit down better and you can inflate the tyre.  Downside is that if you stop to check pressure, the second inflation won't be able to push the valve down.   So start from a completely empty tyre and it works better.   (though test the pump works before releasing all your air!! )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a gas station pump then you are out and about, have a flat tire or very little air in your tires or have a puncture, either way you need air for your tires and in this scenario it is perfectly fine to use the gas station air pump once you are careful. You can use a linen handkerchief or any piece of cloth to put between the air pumps nozzle and the tire nozzle to offset the burst of air from the pump if you are concerned but it is not really needed. Just be careful and underfill rather than overfill. If it's the type of pump that has a pressure gauge on the handle that is ideal, if it's the preset one just set the pressure lower before use.